# Select a count and a count of max values that are bigger than one

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a query that needs to calculate some counts of some columns and the count of maximum value of a column then group by some more criterias.

So far I have the following query:

```
select 
subj.inventoryNum as Inventory,
extract(month from subj.createDate) as month,
oolame.schoolCode as Code,
count(case when max(subVers.verNum) > 0 then 1 end) as deleted,
count(case when subVers.delDate is not null then 1 end) as changed

from 
Subjects subj
inner join SubjectVersions subVers on subVers.subjFk = subj.subjId
inner join SchoolName oolame on oolame.oolameId = subj.oolameFk 

group by 
subj.inventoryNum,
extract(month from subj.createDate),
oolame.schoolCode;
```

It gives me the following error:

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 2 Column: 1
```

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result? you can't use aggregate function contain in an aggregate function.

Comment: @D-Shih The result would be the number of deleted ones and modified ones per version, what would be the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is a little unclear.  Do you want the overall maximum?  The maximum per subject?  Some other maximum?

In any case, you can use a window function in a subquery to get the maximum.  For instance, if you want the maximum per subject:

```
select subj.inventoryNum as Inventory,
       extract(month from subj.createDate) as month,
       oolame.schoolCode as Code,
       sum(case when subVers.max_verNum > 0 then 1 else 0 end) as deleted,
       count(subVers.delDate) as changed
from Subjects subj inner join
     (select subvers.*,
             max(subVers.verNum) over (partition by subVers.subjFk) as max_verNum
      from SubjectVersions subVers
     ) subVers
     on subVers.subjFk = subj.subjId inner join
     SchoolName oolame
     on oolame.oolameId = subj.oolameFk 
group by subj.inventoryNum,
         extract(month from subj.createDate),
         oolame.schoolCode;
```

Comment: I think you have an additional bracket? and what is countsubVers?

Comment: Where is the part where it says "is not null"

Comment: @GingerHead . . . That is what `count()` doesn.